# How to load a UIViewController from a class that does not inherit UIviewController (from a swift file with class )?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, ios-frameworks

I am working on building framework for a widget. I have two files as follows: 
`widgetBuilder.swift` and 
`webWidget.swift`

`widgetBuilder.swift` is file with getters and setters that takes certain values from the app that is going to use this widget framework.

Code from `widgetBuilder.swift`

```swift
import Foundation
class WidgetBuilder {

    private var userId: String!
    private var emailId: String!

    public func setuserId(userId: String) -> WidgetBuilder{
        self.userId = userId
        return self
    } 

    public func setEmailId(emailId: String) -> WidgetBuilder{
        self.emailId = emailId
        return self

    }

    public func build() -> WidgetBuilder{
        // Wanted to load the webview from here 
    }
}
```

Once the initialization is done I would call the build function, I wanted to load the ViewController of `webWidget.swift`

Code from `webWidget.swift`

```swift
class webWidget: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate  {


    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        self.loadWebView()
    }

    public func loadWebView(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    public func loadWidgetScreen() {
        //Something is not correct here  
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WidgetController") 
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

How do I load the webWidget view from the `widgetBuilder.swift` and pass some data along ?

Comment: add import UIKit and now you you can use the uiviewcontroller object in your widgetBuilder.swift

Comment: I got a new one after importing UIKit :   `Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x7fc71dd1d080> on <widget_wrapper.Widget: 0x7fc71df328d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` What does this even mean ?

Comment: using which ref you are presenting the viewcontroller?
can you show the code?

Comment: I created an object for the webWidget in the widgetBuilder and tried calling the ```loadWidgetScreen()```

Comment: in that case your webWidget's view is not showing on the screen currently

Comment: yes , I get warnings that I showed above !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how I solved , Posting it, might be helpful for somebody looking to load a ViewController from a swift file.

Once I call the the `build()` from my swift file , it has to load the view,

Added a `var` that gets the ViewController instance from the parent view that wants to load this widget.

Inside the `widgetBuilder.swift`

```swift
private var clientView: UIViewController?

public init(_ viewController:UIViewController){
    self.clientView = viewController;
}
```

Then,

```swift
public func build(){

    // Widget() creates ViewController instance , this viewcontroller is mapped to a widget.xib file
    let controller: UIViewController = Widget() // Creating the instance of the view class
    self.clientView?.addChild(controller) // self.clientView is the ViewController instance that wants to load widget view 
    self.clientView?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.view.frame = (clientView?.view.bounds)!
    controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    controller.didMove(toParent: clientView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In webWidget.swift 
replace your `loadWidgetScreen()` method with below

```
public func loadWidgetScreen() {
  if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
      while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
          topController = presentedViewController
      }

      // topController should now be your topmost view controller
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WidgetController") 
      self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  else {
    print("topViewController not found")
  }
}
```

Comment: How does adding ```import UIKit``` in widgetBuilder.swift have any effect on that code ? Its not being used anywhere ? '

Comment: you can remove that until and unless you are using some UIKit specific functions / objects in WidgetBuilder

Comment: ```self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)``` actually just presents the controller and it is not displayed the whole screen.